# how to create key value pair from an a array

Tags: javascript, jquery, hashmap, hashtable

This is my json :

```
[["123", "456", "789", "user1"],
 ["987", "654", "321", "user2"]]
```

I have put it in this way in my code:

```
var rows = [ 
  ["123","456","789","user1"] ,
  ["987","654","321","user2"]
];
```

I want user1 and user2 as key and remaining as values. How to create a key value pair from this json?

Comment: I checked it in jsonlint and it showed me valid json@sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ

Comment: Sorry, my bad. ..

Comment: I tried this : for(i=0,i<rows.length, i++){
map[rows[i][4]]=[rows[i][1],rows[i][2],rows[i][3]]
}   but not getting what to do next @CarstenLøvboAndersen

Answer (score 4):

Use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method and generate the object.

```js
var data = [
  ["123", "456", "789", "user1"],
  ["987", "654", "321", "user2"]
];

var res = data
  // iterate over the array elements
  .reduce(function(obj, arr) {
    // define the object property by popping the last element
    // if you dont want to update the origian array 
    // element then take copy of inner array using slice()
    obj[arr.pop()] = arr;
    // return the object reference
    return obj;
    // set initial value as an empty object
  }, {})

console.log(res);
```

---

If you don't want to update the original array :

```js
var data = [
  ["123", "456", "789", "user1"],
  ["987", "654", "321", "user2"]
];

var res = data.reduce(function(obj, arr) {
  obj[arr[arr.length - 1]] = arr.slice(0, -1);
  return obj;
}, {})

console.log(res);
```

---

**UPDATE :** If there is a chance for multiple elements for the same user, then you can combine them.

```js
var data = [
  ["123", "456", "789", "user1"],
  ["987", "654", "321", "user2"],
  ["abc", "def", "ghi", "user1"]
];

var res = data.reduce(function(obj, arr) {
  // initialize propety as an empty array if undefined
  obj[arr[arr.length - 1]] = obj[arr[arr.length - 1]] || [];
  // push the array values into the array
  [].push.apply(obj[arr[arr.length - 1]], arr.slice(0, -1));
  return obj;
}, {})

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Your code will not work if 
data = [
  [ "user1","123", "456", "789"],
  ["987", "654", "321", "user2"]
];

Comment: This code is actually useful. But if I enter 1 more array for user1 , it shows only the new array which I entered.ie if ["123", "456", "789", "user1"], ["abc", "def", "ghi", "user1"],
  ["987", "654", "321", "user2"] it shows user1: abc , def , ghi  and not the before one @PranavCBalan

Comment: @Mary : what's the expected behaviour do you want to combine them

Comment: If I add more arrays for user1 , I should get a single key  user1 and all its values . That is:  user1:["123", "456", "789"] ["abc", "def", "ghi"] and then same for user2 , user3 etc @PranavCBalan

Answer (score 0):

You can simply iterate using [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and push the popped item into an array.

```js
var arr = {};
var rows = [ 
["123","456","789","user1"] ,
["987","654","321","user2"],
  ["12213","45216","78219","user1"],
  ["abc","def","ghi","user1"],
  ["uvw","wxy","xyz","user2"]
 ];
rows.forEach(function(item){  
  var val = item[item.length-1];
  if ( arr[val] ) {   
   arr[item.pop()].push(item);
  } else {
    arr[item.pop()] = [item];
  }
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
```

If you want all the values grouped and mapped to the key :

```js
var arr = {};
var rows = [ 
["123","456","789","user1"] ,
["987","654","321","user2"],
  ["12213","45216","78219","user1"],
  ["abc","123","ghi","user1"],
  ["678","789","890","user2"]
 ];
rows.forEach(function(item){  
  var val = item[item.length-1];
  if ( arr[val] ) {
    arr[item.pop()] = arr[val].concat(item);
  } else {
    arr[item.pop()] = item;
  }
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
```